# How to disable all modifiers at once

Tags: modeling, modifiers, add-on

I know that I can click and drag at monitors to kind of disable modifiers in Blender, but it's not working in heavy objects with ton of modifiers. Is there any addon to do that? Or any workaround?

I heard of the *Display Tools* addon, but unfortunately I didn't find it for Blender 2.93.

Comment: would  a python solution be ok for u?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a built-in add-on called *Modifier Tools*.

With it, you get this little dialog:

[image: Screenshot of Modifier Tools]

Comment: How much do you want as payment my friend ?

Comment: :) - Give it to the actual developers of the Add-on.

Answer (score 6):

**A script.**

*As answered by [@michaelh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234964/15543) Please accept that answer if using modifier tools addon answers your question*

There is an existing addon [modifier tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234964/15543) to multi set all modifiers in the stack of the context object.

**For multiple objects.**

Misread question, as to setting all modifiers on multiple objects.

Iterate over selected objects and set show in render and viewport to `True` if `option = 'ENABLE'`, false with `'DISABLE'` or toggle value.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

option = 'TOGGLE' # in 'ENABLE', 'DISABLE', 'TOGGLE'

for ob in context.selected_objects:
    for mod in getattr(ob, "modifiers", []):
        if option == 'TOGGLE':
            mod.show_viewport = not mod.show_viewport
        else:
            mod.show_viewport = option == 'ENABLE'
        # optional
        #mod.show_render = mod.show_viewport # keep same
```

Note will disable for any `option` not in `'ENABLE', 'TOGGLE'`